# Redirect this url permanently with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to permanently redirect a url but it doesn't seem to work, this is what I have in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
rewriteRule ^modules\.php?name=My_Page$ http://mysite.net/mypage [R=permanent,L]
```

As you can see I want to redirect modules.php?name=My_Page to http://mysite.net/mypage
I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path used in RewriteRule doesn't contain the querystring. Use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=My_Page$
rewriteRule ^modules\.php$ /mypage? [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you. Some of my redirected urls have ?name=My_Page attached to it. Anything I can do to get rid of those?

Comment: See edit above. Just add a `?` and the end of the replacement url.